# Pass array of objects using jquery in spring MVC controller

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass array of files object to spring MVC controller. But I am getting 400 Bad request error.

In my jsp I have written a jquery method to get the array of files.

```
function getFilelist() {
      var files = $('body').data('filelist');
      return files;
}
```

And uploading these all files using post Json method.

---Updated----

I am adding the whole init() method:

```
function init() {
    $('input:button').button();
    $('#submit').button();

    $('#uploadForm').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();   

        alert("uploading..");

        $.postJSON('fileSave.htm', {
            filename: getFilelist()    
        },
                   function(result) {
                       if (result.success == true) {
                           dialog('Success', 'Files have been uploaded!');
                       } else {
                           dialog('Failure', 'Unable to upload files!');
                       }
                   });
    });

    $('#reset').click(function() {
        clearForm();
        dialog('Success', 'Fields have been cleared!');
    });

    $('#upload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                $('body').data('filelist').push(file);
                $('#filename').append(formatFileDisplay(file));
                $('#attach').empty().append('Add another file');
            });
        }
    });

    $("#attach").click(function () {
        $("#upload").trigger('click');
    });

    $('body').data('filelist', new Array());
}
```

Here getFilelist() is the array of file objects. In my controller I have written:

```
@RequestMapping(value="fileSave", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody StatusResponse message(
    @RequestParam("filesAttachedList") FilesAttachedList filesAttachedList) {
  // some code here
}
```

My `FilesAttachedList` class:

```
public class FilesAttachedList implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5944305104394883501L;
    private List<FileAttachment> filesList;

    public List<FileAttachment> getFilesList() {
        return filesList;
    }

    public void setFilesList(List<FileAttachment> filesList) {
        this.filesList = filesList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FilesAttachedList [filesList=" + filesList + "]";
    }
}
```

So how can I pass the array of objects from jquery to controller?

**--updated--**

When I check the browser getFileList returns

```
 Object
 attachableId: null
 attachableType: null
 attachmentContentType: null
 attachmentFileName: "http://localhost:8080/myproject/resources/images.jpg"
 attachmentFileSize: 6994
 attachmentUpdatedAt: null
 createdAt: null
 creatorId: null
 id: null
 name: "images.jpg"
 updatedAt: null
 updaterId: null
 __proto__: Object
 length: 1
 __proto__: Array[0]
```

This is what if I add two image objects

```
 Array[2]
 0: Object
 1: Object
 length: 2
 __proto__: Array[0]
```

**----Update 3 ---**

when I change from `@RequestParam("filesAttachedList") FilesAttachedList filesAttachedList` to `@RequestBody final String filesAttachedList` and add two images it gives me the following string objects. Can I read this string?

```
{
  "filename": [
    {
      "id": null,
      "createdAt": null,
      "updatedAt": null,
      "name": "images.jpg",
      "attachableId": null,
      "attachableType": null,
      "attachmentFileName": "http:\/\/localhost:8080\/myproject\/resources\/images.jpg",
      "attachmentContentType": null,
      "attachmentFileSize": 6994,
      "attachmentUpdatedAt": null,
      "creatorId": null,
      "updaterId": null
    },
    {
      "id": null,
      "createdAt": null,
      "updatedAt": null,
      "name": "lion.jpg",
      "attachableId": null,
      "attachableType": null,
      "attachmentFileName": "http:\/\/localhost:8080\/myproject\/resources\/lion.jpg",
      "attachmentContentType": null,
      "attachmentFileSize": 36670,
      "attachmentUpdatedAt": null,
      "creatorId": null,
      "updaterId": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add what's the data structure (result of `getFilelist()`) from browser debug?

Comment: Hi Xaerxess, I have updated my question.

Comment: Hi Xaerxess, please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: P.S. If you have string filesAttachedList in your controller you can use another JSON deserializer, Gson, to extract the data: `( new Gson() ).fromJson( filesAttachedList, FilesAttachedList.class );`.

Comment: Yes Xaerxess, Its good thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hmm, it means that something is probably wrong with `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` configuration. But I'm glad that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't print `{`, `}`, `[` and `]` characters which are important here, but I assume it's just one Object while your controller expects a list of `FileAttachment` objects.

Either add surround files in JS with array `return [ files ];` or, if it'll always be only on `FileAttachment` change controller to `@RequestParam("fileAttachment") FileAttachment fileAttachment`.

EDIT:

Can you change `@RequestParam("fileAttachment")` to `@RequestParam("filename")`? I see you edited your question meanwhile.

Comment: Hi Xaerxess, Thanks for your response, its more than 1 file attachment, please check my update

Comment: So can you change `@RequestParam("filesAttachedList") FilesAttachedList filesAttachedList` to `@RequestBody final String filesAttachedList` and in debug in your Controller check what is filesAttachedList value?

Comment: Given the update, seems that if you change the argument to `@RequestParam("filename")` it should work. If not, that means your `FileAttachment` class is flawed somehow, because JSON is OK, controller recieves data but `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` doesn't cope with translating JSON to `FileAttachment`.

Comment: @Xaerxess could u help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102452/spring-mvc-415-unsupported-media-type