# Spring MVC 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 3.2 and try to use an ajax post request to submit an array of json objects. If this is relevant, I escaped all special characters.

I am getting an HTTP Status of 415.

My controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save-profile", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String saveProfileJson(@RequestBody String[] profileCheckedValues){
        System.out.println(profileCheckedValues.length);
        return "success";
    }
```

jquery is:

```
jQuery("#save").click(function () {
        var profileCheckedValues = [];
        jQuery.each(jQuery(".jsonCheck:checked"), function () {
            profileCheckedValues.push($(this).val());
        });
        if (profileCheckedValues.length != 0) {
            jQuery("body").addClass("loading");
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: contextPath + "/sample/save-profile",
                data: "profileCheckedValues="+escape(profileCheckedValues),
                dataType: 'json',
                timeout: 600000,
                success: function (data) {
                    jQuery('body').removeClass("loading");
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                    jQuery('body').removeClass("loading");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

and an example of one of the objects from the array I am posting is the following json:

```
{
  "id": "534213341",
  "name": "Jack Lindamood",
  "first_name": "Jack",
  "last_name": "Lindamood",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/jack",
  "username": "jack",
  "gender": "male",
  "locale": "en_US",
  "updated_time": "2013-07-23T21:13:23+0000"
}
```

The error is:

```
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method
```

Why is this error happening - does anyone know?

Comment: Do you have jackson in the classpath?

Comment: yes i have included jackson-core 2.0.6

Comment: This not an array of values, but a map of values.

Comment: this is a single element.

Comment: What do you mean with that? Do you expect an array of the above JSON? Like profiles for multiple users? Where is the name "profileCheckedValues" in your HTTP request? Ah, there's your error: you're not sending application/json even though you set contentType to that. You're sending a parameter named "profileCheckedValues" *which content* is JSON (I guess). But then the HTTP request itself is not JSON; remove that line to make jQuery use the default "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". This way your controller will get JSON though, without is being converted by Spring.

Comment: Ah I missed the paragraph below your JSON. My bad. Still then the above applies. Do you know how to see the HTTP traffic in Chrome or Firebug? Am I right that the above jQuery gets you a parameter named "profileCheckedValues"?

Comment: And then `@RequestParam` might do the trick.

Comment: @Arjan yes this is a profile of multiple users. Could you show me a sample for this? profileCheckedValues in param when i saw through firebug

Comment: Did you try @RequestParam then, or muthu's `HttpServletRequest`? Be sure to peek into the HTTP request to understand what your browser is sending. And remove the `contentType` like I wrote above.

Comment: I tried muthu's HttpServletRequest that is not working for arrays of values but working for single element

Comment: @Arjan I tried with muthu's. it is working fine for each object instead of array

Comment: See my comment to that answer. Also `@RequestParam` should work with arrays.

Comment: (Also, what does *"is not working"* mean? Be precise, please. And comment on muthu's answer -- this is getting to be a very messy question.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try with `HttpServletRequest`. it does not have any problem

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/save-profile", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json",headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public @ResponseBody String saveProfileJson(HttpServletRequest request){
       System.out.println(request.getParameter("profileCheckedValues"));
        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: `@RequestParam` might work as well. And also in the jQuery call, remove setting the `contentType`: sending an array with name `profileCheckedValues` (which *happens* to hold JSON strings, but could have been anything) is not `application/json` but simply the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: And for arrays, use `getParameterValues`.

Comment: Again, @jackyesind, what does *"it does not works"* mean? (What do you see? You need to be specific; you need to be much more detailed.) Also, did you try `getParameterValues`? And `@RequestParam`? Please read [Help Vampires: A Spotter’s Guide](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/). I'm no longer responding to your requests, but: success.

Comment: @Arjan. Sorry. If i use getParameterValues means it returns null only

Comment: How did you test, muthu? [getParameterValues](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) should return the same as getParameter, if there's just one value. But indeed it depends on how jQuery creates the request. That jQuery Ajax request in @jackyesind's question has bugs too.

Comment: Awesome...But why did you use `HttpServletRequest` ? I tried `@ResponseBody final MyObject obj` with the same settings for `consumes` and `headers` but it failed....

Answer (score 6):

1) Add the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-version}</version> // 2.4.3
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-version}</version> // 2.4.3
</dependency>
```

2) If you are using @RequestBody annotation in controller method make sure you have added following in xml file

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

This should resolve the 415 status code issue.

Comment: I had 415 problem because of using codehaus dependency instead of fasterxml. Thanks! Worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add jackson and jackson-databind to the classpath. Spring will pick it up using it's [`MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.html)

#### MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter

> An HttpMessageConverter implementation that can read and write JSON using Jackson's ObjectMapper. JSON mapping can be customized as needed through the use of Jackson's provided annotations. When further control is needed, a custom ObjectMapper can be injected through the ObjectMapper property for cases where custom JSON serializers/deserializers need to be provided for specific types. By default this converter supports (application/json).

Comment: I already included jackson-core-2.0.6.jar.  `public @ResponseBody String saveProfileJson(@RequestBody String[] profileCheckedValues)` instead of string what would i give i don't have objects for that json

Comment: You probably need to add the jackson-databind package as well

Answer (score 2):

I had `consume="application/json"` in my request mapping configuration which expects a json input. When I sent a request which is not a JSON input Spring complained about the 415 Unsupported Media Type. So removing the `consume="application/json"` worked for me. So look into the request input and the accept media type in your Spring controller method signature. A mismatch would throw the 415 error. This will be most likely the reason for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `json` to `application/json` for datatype. And what does your json look like is it [valid](http://jsonlint.com/) ? I have never seen json converted to a String[] before, so this coul dalso be the problem.

Comment: Is there any possible to send array of json to spring controller

Comment: when i checked in firebug the param has valid json. In java side how would i get

Comment: `datatype` is what the server sends back. Also, it's not formatted as a MIME type, but defined by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had to follow these steps to resolve the issue:

**1. Make sure you have the following dependencies:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-version}</version> // 2.4.3
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-version}</version> // 2.4.3
    </dependency>
```

**2. Create the following filter:**

```
    public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            String origin = request.getHeader("origin");
            origin = (origin == null || origin.equals("")) ? "null" : origin;
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "Authorization, origin, content-type, accept, x-requested-with");

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

**3. Apply the above filter for the requests in web.xml**

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.your.package.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I hope this is useful to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just brought up the below line of code in the spring-servlet.xml, it was at the almost end of this xml file. It worked.
    `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and everything looked ok. Other requests working like a charm in the same project. Finally it turned out out that my request object had a duplicate the:

```
@JsonProperty("duplicatePropertyName")
```

entry. The error message:

> 415 Unsupported Media Type

Is really confusing in this case. Hope this helps to people with bad eyes like me ;-)