# Unexpected 'S' in Postman on consuming REST Api

Tags: java, json, rest, maven, spring-boot

I wrote very basic REST service in SpringBootApplication. When I tried to hit the api I am getting response like `Unexpected 'S'`

This is my api,

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping(value="/rally")
    public class CreateProjectApi {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/createProject", 
                produces = { "application/json" }, 
                consumes = { "application/json" }, 
                method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<String> createProj() {
            String s = "Success...";
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(s, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

    }
```

This is my POM.XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.altimetrik.rally</groupId>
    <artifactId>RallyRestApi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>RallyRestApi</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring MVC & REST, use Embedded Tomcat -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rallydev.rest</groupId>
            <artifactId>rally-rest-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am hitting the api through postman with `content-type:application/json` in header. But I am getting Unexpected 'S' as response. I have followed this link [unexpected 's' in response of restful service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211597/unexpected-s-in-response-of-restful-service) but I didnt get any solution from that. Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: That's because your response is not in a JSON format and you specify that you will produce JSON, Error meaning that it is expected { sign because it iexpected JSON but he found S character

Comment: How can I make my response as JSON? @user7790438

Comment: @Nithyananth Your response would need to be an object or a collection/array, which would then be serialized by the converter that Spring finds on the classpath. If you really just want your response to be the text `Success...` then that's not JSON, and you can change your response type to `"text/plain"`. Also, since your service isn't accepting any arguments you don't really need the `consumes` argument in your `RequestMapping`.

Comment: I want to return `"JSON"`, so can you give the sample code like how it should be. @nbrooks

Comment: Either remove the produces element or make the response media type to JSON.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As explained in the comments by both [user7790438](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511588/unexpected-s-in-postman-on-consuming-rest-api#comment76016014_44511588) and [nbrooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511588/unexpected-s-in-postman-on-consuming-rest-api#comment76016994_44511588), the issue is that your response will be plain text (`Success...`), even though you tell it to load JSON (by providing the `Content-Type: application/json` header).

To return JSON, you should return some kind of object, for example, you could create a `ProjectStatus` class like this:

```
public class ProjectStatus {
    private String status;

    public ProjectStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

Now, in your REST controller you should return a `ResponseEntity<ProjectStatus>`, like this:

```
return new ResponseEntity<ProjectStatus>(new ProjectStatus("Success..."), HttpStatus.OK);
```

This will result in the following JSON when you use Postman:

```
{"status": "Success..."}
```

You can pretty much return any object you'd like. An example would be to return the created project in your response.

---

Alternatively, if you don't need JSON, you could provide the `Content-Type: text/plain` header.